# What is the "2016 Moderator Elections" about?

Tags: discussion, meta, moderator-election

Why are Moderator Elections conducted on Stack Overflow ([2016 Moderator Elections](https://stackoverflow.com/election/8))?

How do elected moderators help the Stack Overflow users/community?

Comment: why stack exchange conducts 2016 Moderator Election. did got the notification go through  http://stackoverflow.com/election/8

Comment: @impathuri Because we are electing new community moderators? The election page explains it...

Comment: @AndrewLi then that you have told ,we are here to guided by some one people like you

Comment: @impathuri Hopefully the edit clears the air here. Please read the [election page](http://stackoverflow.com/election/8) carefully, most of what you need to know is explained there.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators

Comment: The [election page](http://stackoverflow.com/election) provides clear information on this.

Answer (score 4):

So you essentially ask what moderators are good for, and the answer is:

- They help maintain the high quality of contents by closing/deleting off topic questions and deleting low quality answers.
- They keep the order by warning and suspending abusive users.
- They handle custom flags of all sorts, e.g. requests to undelete posts, detect voting rings, etc.

In the very beginning, the moderators were selected by Stack Exchange team, but [since 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/election/1) SE decided to let the users vote and choose their moderators, but there's no difference in the roles and responsibility of the Pro Tem moderators and elected moderators.